# Why is my dedicated GPU still utilized even though the game window is on a monitor not plugged into the GPU card?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, gaming

I have two monitors, one is plugged into the GPU card HDMI port (main monitor) and the other one is plugged into the motherboard HDMI port (secondary monitor).

I am playing Tekken 8 on the secondary monitor, but when I open Task Manager I see that the dedicated GPU is still utilized.

How is this possible? Can applications utilize the dedicated GPU even though the dedicated GPU is not outputting display to a monitor?

Comment: "Can applications utilize the dedicated GPU even though the dedicated GPU is not outputting display to a monitor?" - Yes

Comment: @Ramhound ok, so does that mean application programs such as games can route the output of the dedicated GPU out into the motherboard HDMI port?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Your system will use a higher power GPU by default. If the monitor is plugged into another display then the frames will be rendered on the high power GPU and then transferred over PCIe to be shown on the lower power GPU.

You can choose which GPU is used to render particular programs by opening your settings program and going to Display -> Graphics Options where you will find a selector to configure things

The Windows Club has a nice guide at [How to choose different GPU for different Apps in Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/choose-different-gpu-for-different-apps-windows-10)